# Is it possible to generate a simple_form field out of a JSON response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, simple-form

I'm searching for a way to create simple_form fields of all options belonging to a room_type, such that a user can fill in the option_quantity. The room_type is asked first in a form and consequently this input needs to be used for the options belonging to that room_type.

**Current attempt**

Currently, I'm getting al options belonging to this room_type with JQuery, but I don't know how to proceed from here (or maybe there is a better way?)

**Response current attempt**

The following response is generate using my current attempt.

```
{rooms: Array(3), options: Array(2), extra_guests: Array(1)}
rooms: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
extra_guests: [{…}]
options: Array(2)
0: {id: 109, room_type_id: 185, name: "Amazing option", description: "", rank: null, …}
1: {id: 110, room_type_id: 185, name: "Second option", description: "", rank: null, …}
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

Using this JSON, is it possible to create a separate option field for each option with a field where the user is asked to fill in the option_quantity?

**Code**

form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |room| %>
<%= room.input :room_type, collection: @room_type_list, input_html:{
        id: "room_type"
      }%>
<% end %>

<h4>Options</h4>
<!-- List all options for room_type by name and display field for option_quantity  -->
<% end %>

<script >
  // dynamic options for change category
  $(document).on("change", "#room_type", function(){
    var room_type = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/hotels/<%= @hotel.id %>/reservations/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {room_type: room_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {

      var options = response["options"];
      console.log(response);
      console.log(options)
      console.log($("room_type-options").html(response));
      // Code to generate list of options
    }
  });
  });
</script>
```

schema

```
create_table "reservation_options", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "option_id"
    t.bigint "reservation_id"
    t.integer "option_quantity"
    []
    t.index ["option_id"], name: "index_reservation_options_on_option_id"
    t.index ["reservation_id"], name: "index_reservation_options_on_reservation_id"
  end

create_table "options", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "room_type_id"
    t.string "name"
    []
    t.index ["room_type_id"], name: "index_options_on_room_type_id"
  end
```

reservation controller

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  # skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
    @all_options = @hotel.options
    @rooms = []
    @options = []
    @extra_guests = []

    # # Display rooms/options for category
    if params[:room_type].present?
      @rooms = RoomType.find(params[:room_type]).rooms
      @options = RoomType.find(params[:room_type]).options
      @extra_guests = RoomType.find(params[:room_type]).extra_guests
    end
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
        render json: {rooms: @rooms, options: @options, extra_guests: @extra_guests}
      }
      end
    end

    authorize @reservation
  end

private

def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:arrival, :departure, :payment, :reservation_contact_id, option_ids:[],
      reservation_contact_attributes: [:id, :first_name,
      :last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :zipcode, :city, :street, :street_number,
      :email, :phone, :date_of_birth, :country, :company, :gender, :vat_number],
        rooms_attributes: [:id,:name, :room_type_id,
          room_types_attributes: [:id, :name]],
      reservation_options_attributes: [:id, :option_id, :option_quantity, :_destroy,
        options_attributes: [:id, :name, :room_type_id, :description,
          room_types_attributes:[:id, :name]]],
      reservation_extra_guests_attributes: [:id, :extra_guest_id, :extra_guest_quantity, :_destroy,
        extra_guests_attributes: [:id, :name, :room_type_id, :age_table_id,
          room_types_attributes:[:id, :name]]])
  end
```

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :room

  has_many :reservation_options, inverse_of: :reservation, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation_options
  has_many :options, through: :reservation_options
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_type
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_type
end

class RoomType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_type
  has_many :reservation_options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :option_prices, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :option
end
```

**Outputs responses**

`console.log(response); =>`

```
{rooms: Array(3), options: Array(2), extra_guests: Array(1)}
rooms: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
extra_guests: [{…}]
options: Array(2)
0: {id: 109, room_type_id: 185, name: "Amazing option", description: "", rank: null, …}
1: {id: 110, room_type_id: 185, name: "Second option", description: "", rank: null, …}
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

`console.log(options); =>`

```
0: {id: 109, room_type_id: 185, name: "Amazing option", description: "", rank: null, …}
1: {id: 110, room_type_id: 185, name: "Second option", description: "", rank: null, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

`console.log($("#room_type-options").html(response)); =>`

```
jQuery.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#room_type-options"}
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It seems like it would be much more straight forward to return html from your ajax call and then insert that into the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your response and you were completely right. I adjusted my question, to provide more information on the problem I'm trying to solve incl. more input on my current code.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think I would make my routes look something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :hotels do 
    resources :room_types, shallow: true do 
      scope module: :room_types do 
        resources :options, only: [:index]
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Which will give you:

```
  room_type_options GET    /room_types/:room_type_id/options(.:format)   room_types/options#index
   hotel_room_types GET    /hotels/:hotel_id/room_types(.:format)        room_types#index
                    POST   /hotels/:hotel_id/room_types(.:format)        room_types#create
new_hotel_room_type GET    /hotels/:hotel_id/room_types/new(.:format)    room_types#new
     edit_room_type GET    /room_types/:id/edit(.:format)                room_types#edit
          room_type GET    /room_types/:id(.:format)                     room_types#show
                    PATCH  /room_types/:id(.:format)                     room_types#update
                    PUT    /room_types/:id(.:format)                     room_types#update
                    DELETE /room_types/:id(.:format)                     room_types#destroy
             hotels GET    /hotels(.:format)                             hotels#index
                    POST   /hotels(.:format)                             hotels#create
          new_hotel GET    /hotels/new(.:format)                         hotels#new
         edit_hotel GET    /hotels/:id/edit(.:format)                    hotels#edit
              hotel GET    /hotels/:id(.:format)                         hotels#show
                    PATCH  /hotels/:id(.:format)                         hotels#update
                    PUT    /hotels/:id(.:format)                         hotels#update
                    DELETE /hotels/:id(.:format)                         hotels#destroy
```

If needed and/or desired, you can limit the generated routes using `only:` or `except:`. For instance, you could do:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :hotels, only: [] do 
    resources :room_types, only: [], shallow: true do 
      scope module: :room_types do 
        resources :options, only: [:index]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And get just:

```
room_type_options GET    /room_types/:room_type_id/options(.:format)   room_types/options#index
```

You could also get the same thing by doing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'room_types/:room_type_id/options', to: 'room_types/options#index'
end
```

Whichever floats your boat...

Then, I would change my js to something more like:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |room| %>
<%= room.input :room_type, collection: @room_type_list, input_html:{
        id: "room_type"
      }%>
<% end %>

<h4>Options</h4>
  <div id="room-type-options">
    <!-- List all options for room_type by name and display field for option_quantity  -->
  </div>
<% end %>

<script >
  // dynamic options for change category
  $(document).on("change", "#room_type", function(){
    var room_type = $(this).val();
    var room_type_id = # do something here...

    $.ajax({
      url: "/room_types/#{room_type_id}/options",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $("#room-type-options").html(response)
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

A few things to note here:

- You'll need a  `RoomTypes::OptionsController` with an `index` action
- The `index` action should return an html blob of room type options
- You don't need to pass the `hotel_id` because a `RoomType belongs_to :hotel` and the `hotel_id`, therefore, can be derived (if needed) from the `RoomType` (thus the `shallow: true` bit). You can read more about this in the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide
- You'll need to fill in the `var room_type_id =` bit on your own. You should be able to get that from the `room.input` but may need to tweak your code a bit - I'm not sure
- The `$("#room-type-options").html(response)` bit is directionally correct, but may need to be fiddled with because I forget exactly what the response structure is
- That `<div id="room-type-options">` bit may or may not be correct. I haven't hand-crafted html in I don't know how long. (I use haml.)

You can implement the `RoomTypes::OptionsController` by creating an `options_controller.rb` file in a `app/controllers/room_types` folder. It would look like any other controller:

```
# app/controllers/room_types/options_controller.rb
class RoomTypes::OptionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @room_type = RoomType.find_by(params[:room_type_id])
    ... do some stuff ...
    ... render some html ...
    ... do a happy dance ...
  end

end
```

Because this controller is namespaced, you can have it at the same time as you have your regular `OptionsController` and `RoomTypesController` and there won't be any conflict.

Comment: thank you so much for the elaborate answer. The ```var room_type``` already provides the room_type_id and so far I've implemented your answer up to the point of the controller  ```RoomTypes::OptionsController``` .  As there is already a RoomTypes controller, I was wondering how the ``` RoomTypes::OptionsController``` can be implemented as I need the other controller for other (existing) features? Furthermore, I will add the current output of ```$("#room-type-options").html(response) ``` to my question. Again, thanks for your help!